# I am trying to open the React Native application but I have this problem What is the solution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

```
$ react-native run-android
error React Native CLI uses autolinking for native dependencies, but the following modules are linked manually:
  - @react-native-community/geolocation (to unlink run: "react-native unlink @react-native-community/geolocation")
  - react-native-bluetooth-status (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-bluetooth-status")
  - react-native-device-info (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-device-info")
  - react-native-i18n (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-i18n")
  - react-native-image-picker (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-image-picker")
  - react-native-ux-cam (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-ux-cam")
  - react-native-vector-icons (to unlink run: "react-native unlink react-native-vector-icons")
```

This is likely happening when upgrading React Native from below 0.60 to 0.60 or above. Going forward, you can unlink this dependency via "react-native unlink " and it will be included in your app automatically. If a library isn't compatible with autolinking, disregard this message and notify the library maintainers.
Read more about autolinking: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1225 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\walleterp-mobile\node_modules@react-native-community\geolocation\android\build.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':@react-native-community_geolocation'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.library']

Comment: could you provide your android grandle info.(android/app/build.grandle, android/settings.grandle, android/build.grandle)

Comment: Thank you ..it is work finally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same issues in my last project,
You can try to unlink with this command : react-native unlink
And remove all dependencies : yarn remove or npm-uninstall
And you delete the yarn.lock , package-lock.json and npm-package-lock.json

And delete the "build" folder in the folder 'Android',
Then u can reinstall with yarn install or npm-install, 
And try react-native run-android,

Personnally I have created a new project and reinstall all depedencies without react-native link, because this bug is a configuration problems and appear with the new version of React Native,

Hope it will help you

Comment: The build failure does not have anything to do with the auto-linking.

Answer (score 1):

just delete the build folder and try again.